# MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE with fields terminated by non-ASCII character

Tags: mysql, file, load, special-characters

I have a lowercase [thorn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_%28letter%29) separated file that I need to load into a MySQL database (5.1.54) using the `LOAD DATA INFILE ...` query.

The file I'm trying to load is located on the same server as the MySQL database, and I'm issuing the query from a Windows machine using [SQLYog](http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/), which uses the MySQL C client library.

I'm having some major issues, I've tried using the `FIELDS TERMINATED BY 0x00FE` syntax using all the variations of the [thorn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_%28letter%29) character I can think of, and I've tried changing the character set of the connection (`SET NAMES ...`), but I consistently get the warning...

```
Warning Code : 1638
Non-ASCII separator arguments are not fully supported
```

...and all the data loads into the first column.

Is there any way around this at all? Or am I resigned to pre-processing the file with `sed` to replace all the [thorn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_%28letter%29)'s with a more sensible character before loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to fix the file by replacing the non-ASCII character with a character that MySQL's `LOAD DATA INFILE ...` would understand.

1. Use `od` to get the octal byte value of the offending character - `od -b file.log` - in this case it's `376`.
2. Use `grep` to make sure the character you want to replace it with doesn't already exist in the file - `grep -n '|' file.log`.
3. Use `sed` and `printf` to replace the non-ASCII character - `sed -i 's/'$(printf '\376')'/|/g' file.log`.

Answer (score 0):

I have succeeded to load this data with [Data Import tool](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/data-export-import.html) (CSV format) in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/). I just set 'Þ' as custom delimiter. The import from the CSV format is fully supported in free Express Edition.

Comment: It's an option, but ideally I'd like to find a way of importing the file from the same server as the DB.

Comment: This file should be accessible to application. The Data Import tool supports command line, you could automate it on the server (of course, if it is possible).